# Get URL content with jquery

Tags: jquery

I know get content in PHP with `file_get_contents('url')` but I don't know how to get content with jQuery. please guide me how to load content of URL: http://vnexpress.net.

Comment: What is the context? What content are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335198/how-to-load-url-into-div-tag

Comment: Have your PHP get the content, and send it on to the client.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the $.get() or $.load() functions, depending on how you want to use the HTTP content. $.get() will let you manipulate the content, $.load() will let you place it into an element on your page.

[Reference for load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

[Reference for get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: While this would indeed get the content from a given url, it won't work because of the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://api.jquery.com/load/