# CORS jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, cors

I'm having troubles with an ajax request. I was getting the error

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

So what I tried was this jQuery ajax request:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
request.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it is still not working. I am still getting the error.

How should I fix this?

Comment: does API serve `jsonp`?

Comment: I should get this out of it `{"ticker":{"high":0.00061,"low":0.00045,"avg":0.00053,"vol":2284.80958,"vol_cur":4421342.40061,"last":0.00051,"buy":0.00052,"sell":0.00051,"updated":1386427668,"server_time":1386427668}}`

Comment: this is a cross domain request issue...google `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `same origin policy`. If API doesn't serve `jsonp` will need to use a server proxy to obtain data

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's easy, you should set server http response header first. **The problem is not with your front-end javascript code.** You need to return this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:your domain
```

In [Apache config files](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html), the code is like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

In nodejs,the code is like this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

Comment: thanks!! especially for the node js code, it works great. Is there any way to set the header by default instead to set it in every post/get handler?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js

Comment: I ran into this on an app of mine, and the problem was actually not server side - I was POST ing to the wrong URL entirely.