# GET data: net::ERR_INVALID_URL for jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

The page in question is http://www.virtualfestivals.com/index.cfm?refresh=1 and when I'm using Google Chrome (F12), under "console" it says

```
GET data: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

I've narrowed it down to the following which is contained in an external JS file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#editformdialog').dialog({ // THIS LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR RIGHT BEFORE .dialog
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close")
            },
            "Save": function () {
                selectAjaxSelects();
                submitEditForm();
                $(this).dialog("close")
            }
        },
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 525,
        minWidth: 525
    });
    $().mousemove(function (e) {
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        mouseX = e.pageX
    })
});
```

The DIV in question is

```
<div xmlns:udf="http://www.virtualfestivals.com/udf" xmlns="" id="editformdialog" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Anything obvious to anyone out there?

Comment: is this div dynamically loaded, or it's present from the begining?

Comment: Yes, it's there from the beginning

Comment: It may seem elementary, but please try console.log($('#editformdialog')) before dialog function. And see if it returns length>0 elements.

Comment: and second possible issue can be .. your selectajax function (I think) uses normal ajax call to this external link.. which is not permissible by jquery.. read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: It returns `[object Object]` and as for the second possible, not sure where/what you mean sorry

Comment: You are using chrome right, so console.log()'s result can be expanded to see the length of values returned.. check it out.

Comment: Sorry yes, it gives a length of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.ui-resizable-handle {     
position: absolute;     
font-size: .1px;     
z-index: 99999;     
display: block;     
background-image: url(data:); 
}
```

That was the issue within a CSS file - the background image was trying, for some reason, to call `data:`

Answer (score 1):

**First possible issue:** 
            The div is not loaded to dom when you are trying to use `$('#editformdialog')`.
            And as you mentioned it gives length of 1. Then this is not the issue.

**Second possible issue** can be .. your `selectajaxselects function` (I think) uses `normal ajax` call to this external link..
            which is not permissible by `jquery`..
            read more [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request)
            **BUT** before calling save, it should not give any ERROR
**try commenting that functions call and executing again**

**Third possible issue:**
            dialog function is not present. May be jqueryui is not working or not included.
 Try calling dialog function on a simple div.

Comment: I tried using the example shown here http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ (default) and it wouldn't work. Something is afoot! Will dig around a bit more

Comment: OKAY, then I am sure, your jqueryui is not included in the rendered output. Please view the page source, and click on the jqueryui include link, see if it points to jqueryui source.

Comment: For a try copy paste code from here http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/10/jquery-ui-dialog-example.html and check it out IT WORKS, then compare and modify your imports/code.

Comment: The CSS seemed to be the issue! `.ui-resizable-handle {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .1px;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(data:);
}` - the `data` bit

Comment: Glad, you found the issue. really was strange. :)