# How to disable CORS for jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have Jquery Code Sample.Here I need to put the content of one page inside a particular div

```
 var ajax_load = "<img src='ajax-loader.gif'  alt='loading...'>";
     $('#id').html(ajax_load).load("https://url/demo/Sample");
```

Due to CORS my code is not working.In my server CORS is enable but request is not coming to server also,How to handle the issue,

If I am trying the same with normal Html (From Same Domain )I am not getting it correctly

Comment: CORS **relaxes** security restrictions. It shouldn't be able to prevent your code from working (although the lack of it could). What makes you think CORS is causing your problem? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Can you open javascript debugger and see what error that appear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CORS jQuery AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request)

Comment: Hi @Jon Kartago Lamida     This is the error I am getting   ::::::
 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://url I am requesting//Sample. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. Sample

Comment: I am requesting a Jsp Page Sample is the URL mapping for my JSP Page.

Comment: @AAAAAA — That error message says the problem is that CORS is not enabled. Its entirely the opposite to the problem you said you had.

Comment: Duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).