# Asynchronous Request Fails, whereas Synchronous Request makes way through and works as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asynchronous, cross-domain

I have been tweaking this script for a while and as I had mentioned in the question, my code works just fine in the non-asynchronous mode, whereas when I change `async:true` , the code just fails.

Here is my code.

```
       $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "http://someotherserver.com/sendmail.php",
                data: { resp: data },
                async: false
                })

                    .done(function( msg )
                     {
                        alert(msg); // Works when async:false              
                     })                         

                     .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
                     {
                       if(textStatus == 'timeout')
                       {     
                        alert('Failed from timeout');
                       }
                     });
```

There is nothing much in the `sendmail.php` which resides on my friend's server with `CORS` enabled there.

**sendmail.php**

```
<?php
file_put_contents('request.txt',json_encode($_REQUEST));
echo "filecreated";
```

The problem is when I change the `async : true` , the request.txt file never gets created on that server whereas if I change `async : false` it works as expected.

The thing is I want this request to be **asynchronous** , not synchronous.

Can somebody have any thoughts on this? If anymore information needed, I will be ready to provide.

Comment: You have to add `Origin` HTTP header if you make CORS request

Comment: But it did work in the synchronous mode. CORS is enabled in the other server where the PHP file is present.

Comment: Perhaps that's affected by the server specifics. However normal [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request **should** contain `Origin:` header. Otherwise it is not `CORS` request.

Comment: @hindmost, Thanks , but this answer says there is nothing to do with JS code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20442852/1742429

Comment: @CatherineTyler still weird that it works in sync mode. Any idea why?