# Why is Parse.User.become getting a 404?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
Parse.User.become("session-token-here").then(function (user) {
  // The current user is now set to user.
}, function (error) {
 // The token could not be validated.
});
```

triggers:
https://api.parse.com/1/users/me
which returns a 404

Yet I have a user table set up and have a session token I need to validate.

Comment: REST API works well. But the above js method hits a 404 block

Comment: Please make sure that you are not making a cross origin ajax request. If yes, then check out this SO post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: Do you mean this should be done within cloud code on parse server?