# OAuth2 redirection fails with CORS error

Tags: redirect, spring-security, oauth-2.0, cors, restful-authentication

I have a RESTful service which I have secured using `Spring Security` and `pac4j-oauth`. An important detail is that Google is acting as the `OAuth2` server-- we need the user's Gmail address to know if they are a legal user of our system, and eventually the service will also need access to their calendar.

When the user first accesses a protected resource (typing in the URL) they get redirected to Google. Once they have authenticated they get redirected back to our service. This works fine.

The problem is that I want to call the service using `Ajax`. When I issue the first `Ajax` call it gets back a redirect to Google. This could mess up the `Ajax` call but in fact it doesn't even get that far. The browser sees the redirect and throws a `CORS` error: **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:8443' is therefore not allowed access."**

I'm at a loss how to handle this. Suggestions would be welcome.

Some thoughts:

1. If I replace the regular `Ajax` call with a `JSONP` call, the redirection still causes an error (because it returns a URL instead of a `JSONP` script) but maybe the client could detect that and navigate to Google on behalf of the service? Once the user authenticates, the client could then take them back to the protected resource again?

   This feels wrong though. For one thing it means that future `Ajax` clients of the RESTful service would have to jump through the same hoops. I'd prefer the clients not to have any dependencies on the server's security implementation.
2. While `CORS` errors are common enough, I've only found a couple other people complaining about them specifically with `OAuth2` authentication. So I'm also wondering if we took a wrong turn with our architecture somewhere.  What exactly are we doing that's so unusual?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have. The solutions there require adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the server's response. That's fine if you are running your own OAuth2 server, but the response in this case is coming from Google. I *might* be able to add it to the redirect request itself, but I suspect that won't help. (If it did, CORS checks would be so easily bypassed that they would seem to be meaningless.)

Comment: I have a similar issue: cors is enabled and I am able to do a request from my angular2 client to the backend, however once I try to use backend/login I get into trouble:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/login/facebook. The request was redirected to 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?, which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
Seems like your answer is a holy grail. Thanks

Comment: Seems like instead of directly calling from client the backend/login which implicitly redirects to facebook, you have to provide a link instead, so the browser gets redirected explicitly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135012/spring-security-angular-2-cors-unable-to-redirect-facebook-signin

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation here are my conclusions.

I'll start with #2 first. Yes, we probably took a wrong turn. Specifically, `OAuth2` was designed for *authorization*, not authentication. (Though if we had been running our own `OAuth2` server we might have gotten away with it.)

Google supports authentication of course: see their docs for [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). But note the two options they list.

1. Code it into the client. This doesn't work well for a `RESTful` service.
2. [One-time authorization code flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow). This option makes perfect sense for a RESTful service. But again it's not intended to authenticate the user; it's about letting the user authorize our service to access their calendar. And they only  need to do this once.

So the plan is that we'll have one webpage that offers the option to authorize our services to access their Google calendar. The user will click on the link explicitly to get the authorization from Google-- the `RESTful` service won't need to redirect their browser. This avoids the `CORS` problem. The client will then post Google's access token to our `RESTful` service.

Note that other consumers of our service don't need to implement this, they just need to let the user authenticate in a way that doesn't require a redirection to a third-party. Initially we'll use our own user/pwd database, with an eye towards hooking into a company directory or `SSO` in the future. `Spring Security` supports numerous options of course.

So: we had to compromise our original plan, but now we are dealing with flows that are well documented and have sample code. So I expect things will go much smoother from now on.

I hope this helps someone avoid the same `OAuth2` design mistake we made, namely using it with a third-party to authenticate users of our `RESTful` service. There are more appropriate ways to authenticate users.