# Spring-Security + Angular 2 + CORS. Unable to redirect Facebook signin

Tags: facebook, angular, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm building an application that uses Angular 2 on the front end, and Spring Boot on the backend. I am using Spring-Security and Spring Social to allow login through Facebook. I thought I had configured CORS correctly, but I am getting the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook. The request was redirected 
to 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=1113908502021844&respo…alhost%3A8080%2Fauth%2Ffacebook&state=d4fb1987-9042-4d49-8bf9-6b5ec94c45f6', 
which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

My security config looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/signup/**", "/user/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .and()
        .headers() //might need defaults disabled
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()                
        .rememberMe()
            .and()
        .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());

}
```

My CORS config:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT"));

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

My frontend request (blocks both **get()** and **post()**):

```
facebookAuth(){
let tokenUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook';
let headers1 = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

return this.http.get(tokenUrl,  {headers: headers1});
```

}

Last, my network info:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here? CORS only seems to block the Facebook redirect, while letting other requests through without issue.

Comment: You simply can not request the login dialog via script, you have to redirect the user‘s browser to the dialog address directly. (The obvious reason for this is that it helps prevent phishing – users can check the address bar in their browser to verify that they are indeed entering their credentials in the FB login form, and not just any site that is trying to fake it.)

Comment: So this is an issue with the Angular code then? My understanding of Spring documentation is that i'm simply supposed to make a call to the API and Spring Social handles the dance.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook` is what redirects to the FB login dialog – so you can not load that first URL via AJAX (which is what you are doing with `return this.http.get(tokenUrl,  {headers: headers1});`), you have to make the browser load that URL directly.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a moron. Changed to just hitting <a href> and it works. Thank you!!!