# XMLHttpRequest cannot load " ...No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." -- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I have being having issue with this request recently .And what baffles me most is the fact that the issue doesn't occur on localhost until I deploy to my machine. I was then forced to change my code to support cross domain requests, as suggested  [Here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.my/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html).

Before it was

```
 $.get('//js.mysite.com/javascript.php', options, function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(idx) {
                .....
             },
            'xml'
        );
```

Now I changed to

```
 $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '//js.mysite.com/javascript.php/',
            data : options,
            dataType : 'xml',
            success : function(xml) {
           .....

             },
            jsonp: 'jsonp'
        });
```

Both work fine on my local machine. However they fail on my dev machine. When I check under the network on my dev browser, and check through the request header, I realized that the request URL on the hosted site is returned as

```
Request Url https://js.mysite.com/javascript.php?prefix=prefix&media=2&campaign=15&mode=txt
```

and my local machine

```
 Requst Url http://js.mysite.com/javascript.php?prefix=prefix&media=2&campaign=15&mode=txt
```

When I changed the https to http from the link return by the hosted site, it works fine . My question is where does the https comes from ? How do I change my code to support such changes considering it returns https on my hosting site and http on the local. The hosted site returns 404 error with the error message `xmlhttprequest cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested`.

Any help, suggestion or better explanation would highly be appreciated.

Comment: it won't work with client side, read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request

Answer (score 1):

1. CORS requiers scheme to be set as well as domain. So you need to check that https://js.mysite.com is added to CORS-allowed section of your server (or use wildcard "*")
2. You use default schema ("//") and it suits majour cases. Changing it to http will couse secuirity issues: most browsers would block http requests from https site. So you have two options: to change site you are requesting from to http, or allow CORS requests to https://js.mysite... (check that ssl exists and works there first of all)

Comment: CORS-allowed section of my server ?  How do i configure that sir? DO i have to that in the code or would that be done by the admin ?

Comment: Both ways: your can do it in config file (web.config for IIS, .htaccess for apache and so on) or with code in handler as Mr Neo mentioned header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTPS` comes from whatever protocol the webpage is being served on.  i.e. if your remote server is forcing an SSL connection it's going to use `HTTPS`.

This is because the `//` on your `url : '//js.mysite.com/javascript.php/',` tells your client to use the protocol of the webpage that is currently making the request.

edit: My guess is that your remote server isn't supporting the HTTPS requests.  You may to enable SSL, or simply use HTTP on your app.